# Creación de ejecutable que debe incluir subcarpetas usando pyinstaller + fichero .spec

Tags: python, pyinstaller

llevaré como 20 horas de búsquedas y pruebas y no he conseguido aun sacar esto adelante.

**Escenario**:

- Un fichero bot.py en la raiz, con el fichero .spec y sus especificaciones concretas.
- Una carpeta con módulos
- Dos carpetas con ficheros que el bot lee y/o escribe

**Qué se busca:**

- Generar el exe y que detecte los módulos en primer lugar.
- Luego
  además el exe debe poder leer y escribir en las carpetas _files y
  _config (en cada caso lo que se haya programado)

**Estructura de ficheros:**

```
bot.py
bot.spec

--_modules
-- -- indicators.py
-- -- globalVars.py
-- -- prices.py

-- _files
-- -- logs
-- -- historic.txt

-- _config
-- -- config.txt
```

**Fichero bot.py**

```
import _modules.globalVars as gv
import _modules.indicators as ind
import _modules.prices as pr
....
```

**Fichero .spec**

```
block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(
    ['bot.py'],
    pathex=['C:\\Users\\vc\\Desktop\\scripts\\bot\\_config', 'C:\\Users\\vc\\Desktop\\scripts\\bot\\_files', 'C:\\Users\\vc\\Desktop\\scripts\\bot\\_modules'],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
    hiddenimports=['globalVars', 'indicators','prices'],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=['C:\\Users\\vc\\Desktop\\scripts\\bot\\_config\\config.txt'],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    [],
    exclude_binaries=True,
    name='bot',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=True,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
    icon='icon.ico',
)
coll = COLLECT(
    exe,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    name='bot',
)
```

Con todo esto, ejecuto `pyinstaller .\bot.spec` y todo se compila adecuadamente. Pasados un par de minutos me ha generado las carpetas /dist y /build y se puede localizar el exe en /dist/bot/bot.exe sin problema. Al ejecutarlo, por mil combinaciones que he probado, siempre devuelve el error de que no encuentra el módulo "_modules"

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_modules'
```

Según he visto en la documentación de pyinstaller, debo añadir las rutas de dónde se encuentran mis módulos usando el parámetro `pathex` dentro del fichero .spec, cosa que ya está configurada.

> -p DIR, --paths DIR A path to search for imports (like using PYTHONPATH). Multiple paths are allowed, separated by ':', or use this
> option multiple times. Equivalent to supplying the pathex argument in
> the spec file.

Por otro lado he probado también a añadir los nombres de los módulos que quiero importar en el parámetro `hiddenimport`, pero tampoco ha funcionado

Estoy convencida de que estoy haciendo lo más complicado de todo el proceso pero estoy dejándome lo más simple y no soy capaz de verlo... alguna sugerencia o idea para probar?

*Como nota final*: mi idea es lograr el fichero .exe (no me importa si es un --onefile o si debe ir con los archivos y carpetas que se generan al no poner --onefile) para poder ponerlo en una carpeta con las dos carpetas de `_files` y `_config` para poder funcionar de forma autónoma sin nada más.

Comment: Has probado copiar la carpeta _modules, _files y _config en la misma carpeta donde se encuentra ubicado tu .exe?

Comment: No lo he probado @williamrb pero no es la solución porque eso sería dejar los .py con el código visible a quién pueda usar el bot y no es lo deseado tampoco. Quiero dejar todo el .py empaquetado y no visible. Sé que luego revertir el proceso es algo que se puede hacer, pero bueno, ya toca currárselo un poco y no es tan simple como "abrir y leer"

Comment: Copia una instalación de Python con todas las dependencias de tu proyecto, ahí tienes tu ejecutable con todo.

Comment: Nota: los módulos de Python que hacen eso, hacen exactamente lo que te puse arriba: empaquetar intérprete y dependencias.

Comment: Una instalación de Python, no un ambiente virtual

Comment: Disculpa @williamrb pero no lo entiendo. Si genero la carpeta `dist` con el exe y los varios ficheros y carpetas que genera por si mismo, y a esa estructura le añado mi carpeta _modules con los ficheros .py dentro... vale, funcionará pero no es lo que busco porque estaría distribuyendo ficheros .py con el código legible por cualquiera, y es precisamente lo que quiero evitar. Sé que un exe generado para python se puede "descompilar", y luego incluso desencriptar y quedar legible, pero oye... ya es un buen currazo que se tienen que dar

Comment: Compila con optimizaciones y genera un `.pyo`, igual vas a ver el bytecode generado e igual te pueden hacer ingeniería inversa. Si te preocupa demasiado eso puedes hacer tu propio sistema de encriptación-desencriptación como hacen los juegos modernos con Denuvo, por poner un ejemplo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo usar `Nuitka` es mas potente y crea ejecutables con menos peso

```
py -m nuitka --standalone --disable-console --include-data-files=./img/*.png=./img/ --include-data-files=./*.py=./ --include-data-files=./*.qss=./ --mingw64 --windows-icon-from-ico=./img/clock.png  --enable-plugin=pyside6 --python-flag=-O --jobs=1 --output-filename=reloj  --company-name=Sinergia --file-version=1.0 --file-description="Software que da la hora y la fecha" --product-version=1 --output-dir=estable --main=main.py --assume-yes-for-downloads
```

Comment: Me gusta la opción pero no he sido capaz de que funcione.
Ejecutando `python -m nuitka --follow-imports .\bot.py` y tras esperar un buen rato de compilación, me genera el .cmd y el .exe. Ejecutando cualquiera de ambos vuelvo a los mismos errores que con pyinstaller. Me dice que no existe la ruta `_config`. Ok, copio la carpeta y también `_files` en la ruta del cmd y del exe, al reintentar ya no da error por estas carpetas pero en el momento de cargar los módulos de `_modules` se cierra la aplicación. Esto será porque no los ha incluído como embebidos a pesar del usar --follow-includes?

Comment: BIEN !!! Parece que `python -m nuitka --follow-imports --standalone --windows-icon-from-ico=icon.ico .\bot.py` ha hecho la magia !!!! Únicamente he tenido que poner las carpetas `_files` y `_config` en la misma ruta que se ha generado `bot.dist` y todo parece arrancar. Lo dejaré un par de días a ver si es cierto que funciona como espero y de ser así.. tenemos solución y ganador de la recompensa !!! Gracias @lunático

Comment: Pasate por aca y seras bienvenida   https://t.me/wikypython

Comment: Agrégate y te enseñare como usar Nuitka sin que tengas que mover nada

Answer (score 0):

Configura un archivo myscript.spec, sigue estos pasos: siguiente instrucción:

Abre una terminal y navega hasta la ubicación de tu script de Python. Ejecuta el siguiente comando para generar el archivo .spec: pyinstaller --name nombre_de_tu_aplicacion --onefile tu_script.py

Asegúrate de reemplazar nombre_de_tu_aplicacion con el nombre deseado para tu aplicación y tu_script.py con el nombre de tu script de Python.

Después de ejecutar el comando, se generará un archivo .spec en la misma ubicación donde se encuentra tu script de Python.

El archivo .spec es un archivo de configuración de PyInstaller que especifica cómo se debe construir el ejecutable de tu aplicación. Puedes abrir el archivo .spec con un editor de texto para personalizar la configuración si es necesario. Una vez que hayas generado el archivo .spec, puedes usarlo para construir el ejecutable de tu aplicación ejecutando el siguiente comando:

```
 pyinstaller myscript.py --hidden-import=tiktoken_ext.openai_public -- 
 hidden-import=tiktoken_ext
```

Explicación Se usa el argumento `--hidden-import` para forzar a `PyInstaller` a incluir `tiktoken_ext.openai_public` y `tiktoken_ext` en el ejecutable que está generando. Esto puede ser necesario cuando `PyInstaller` no puede detectar automáticamente todas las dependencias de un script.

Esta solución puede ayudar a otros programadores que encuentren un error similar al utilizar PyInstaller, especialmente si están utilizando módulos o paquetes similares en sus scripts. Sin embargo, este consejo podría no aplicarse a todas las situaciones de error similares, ya que la causa exacta del error puede variar dependiendo del script y el entorno

Puede que que quizá te sirva esto:(es la configuracion remendad)

```
block_cipher = None
added_files=[('./data/*.*','data'),('./ui/*.*','ui')]

a = Analysis(['main_gia.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\tasl\\Documents\\bitbucket\\gia_python'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=added_files,
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
        a.scripts,
        exclude_binaries=True,
        name='main_gia',
        debug=False,
        strip=False,
        upx=True,
        console=False,
        icon='./data/icon_gia.ico')
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='main_gia',
               icon='./data/icon_gia.ico')
```

Comment: Gracias por intentarlo @cracker-trom, pero en realidad, lo mismo que pones aquí es lo que hay en la docu de Pyinstaller y ya lo he leído y releído. De hecho, en mi publicación ya indico que he leído esta documentación. El fichero .spec ya lo tengo creado desde el principio y ya lo he personalizado como pensé que debía hacerlo, pero no funciona... por eso pregunto y recompenso a quién pueda ayudarme con la parte que, a buen seguro, se me está escapando ;)

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, te sugerimos revisar [answer], saludos.